# Link to JCenter to release to Maven central missing

Tags: maven, bintray, jcenter

I'm maintaining the OSS library RxJava and up until today, we were able to release versions of it through bintray which were also synced to maven properly. The last successful sync was on February 25.

Today, the CI release failed with 403 forbidded and quoting

> To be synced to Maven Central your package needs to be included in the JCenter repository.

When I visited the [bintray page](https://bintray.com/reactivex/RxJava/RxJava) of the project, it seems there is no link to JCenter there indeed. The neighboring ReactiveX libraries (such as [RxKotlin](https://bintray.com/reactivex/RxJava/RxKotlin)) have this link. I can't remember if we had this link before or not.

Is it possible the link was somehow severed or there was a recent change that mandates JCenter linkage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there was an issue that was resolved by the Bintray team developers.

Your packages are now linked and available for download via Jcenter.

We apologize for the inconvenience.

JFrog team.